# MultiSelect gesture like Google Photos app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sensors, android-gesture, google-photos

I want to implement multi select gesture in my app [like in new Google Photos App here](http://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/06/google-photos-select-100588480-orig.gif):

[image]

I have tried [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/3830694), but couldn't do this. **Can anyone just guide me?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally I found a library here. https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview.

Answer (score 8):

Check out this small project here: https://github.com/serzhby/MultiselectGridViewSample. It's far from perfect, but I think the idea of implementation should be clear. You should change the code for your particular need.

The main idea is to use `GridView` class as a base class. By overriding the `onTouchEvent` method we can detect which element was selected. Further processing is pretty staightforward.

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.